# Translate UI elements in Silverstripe

Tags: fluent, silverstripe-4

**Is there support for translating ui elements in silverstripe 4?**

I know that Fluent module exists to translate content. But what if I want to translate, for example, buttons?

Or is it possible that Fluent can handle this?

Comment: Silverstripe seems to have support for this: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/i18n/

Answer (score 0):

If by buttons, you mean content that's been hard-coded into a template or PHP file rather than input in a CMS field then yes.

You will use T functions:

- https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/i18n/#the-t-function
- https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/i18n/#usage-in-template-files

You'll then need to run a build task to generate a YML file which you can then translate into all necessary languages

- https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/i18n/#collecting-text